# I am getting Check Marx error in visual force page. The error was reflected XSS

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Explicit render after an onload callback</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
****var lexOrigin = 'https://{!$CurrentPage.parameters.lcHost}';****
          var verifyCallback = function(response) {
            var message = document.getElementById("g-recaptcha-response").value;
              parent.postMessage({ resp: message, action :'success' }, lexOrigin);
          };
          var onloadCallback = function() {
              grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
                  'sitekey' : '{!$Label.Site_Key}',
                  'callback' : verifyCallback,
              });
          };
              //console.log(' hi'+lexOrigin);
              parent.postMessage({'state':'LOADED', 'vfHost': "{!LEFT($CurrentPage.URL,FIND('/',$CurrentPage.URL,9))}"}, lexOrigin);

        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <form action="?" method="POST">
          <div id="html_element"></div>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none"/>
        </form>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async="" defer="">
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, it is possible to inject (possibly malicious) code in to your script.

```
/apex/yourPageName/lcHost='%3Balert(%22Hello%20World%22)%3B%20var%20y%20%3D%20'
```

Will display a harmless message, but this could be used to inject an entire new script, steal your cookies, etc.

Instead, make sure you use [JSENCODE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) to prevent these sorts of attacks:

```
var lexOrigin = 'https://{!JSENCODE($CurrentPage.parameters.lcHost)}';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer It worked and passed the Checkmarx scan results.